# Question about interior of a set

Tags: general-topology

I'm given two normed vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a linear map $T:X \rightarrow Y$. Also given is that $0$ lies in the interior of $T(B(0,r))$ for some $r>0$.

I now have to show that $0$ lies in the interior of $T(B(0,\epsilon))$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. 
I know that $B(0,\epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon}{r}B(0,r)$, where I use the notation
$\frac{\epsilon}{r}B(0,r)=\{\frac{\epsilon}{r}x |x\in B(0,r)\}$. But how do I continue from here?

I'm very confused about the interior of a set of the from $\lambda V$. Is it true that $int(\lambda V) = \lambda(int(V))$? Or is one of them included in the other?

And what about sets of the form $\lambda + V$?

My apologies for the probably dumb questions but the thing is that I'm quite dumb myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that $\text{int}\,(\lambda V)=\lambda\,\text{int}\,V$.

Suppose that $x\in \text{int}\,V$. Then there exists $c>0$ with $B(x,c)\subset V$. Note that $B(x,c)=x+B(0,c)$. Then
$$
\lambda V\supset \lambda B(x,c)=\lambda x+\lambda B(0,c)=\lambda x+B(0,\lambda c)=B(\lambda x,\lambda c).
$$
So $\text{int}\,(\lambda V)\supset\lambda\,\text{int}\,V$. Now
$$
\frac1\lambda\,\text{int}\,(\lambda V)\subset \text{int}\,(\frac1\lambda\,\lambda V)=\text{int}\,V,
$$
so $\text{int}\,(\lambda V)\subset\lambda\,\text{int}\,V$

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!